# How to setup onmylocationbuttonclicklistener using kotlin?

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, mylocationoverlay

In java, the following code will be used to setup override in My Location Button.

```java
    //add location button click listener
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new 
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
        {
            //TODO: Any custom actions
            return false;
        }
    });
```

However, in kotlin, I can't find any tutorial to learn how to setup the new action in kotlin. I have seen some tutorial on translating java code into kotlin. However, it is not successful.

```
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener( { 
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            override fun onMyLocationButtonClick() : Boolean {
                //TODO: Any custom actions
                return false;
            }
        }
    )}
```

It shows

> Type Mismatch.
>      Required: Boolean
>      Found: GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener
>      Expected value of type Boolean

I expected this override is worked but I can't find any tutorial about this. Can anyone solve my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write. Kotlin supports Java SAM interfaces

```
map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
    // todo
    false
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. If I want to use the value of latitude and longitude after I press the my location button. How can I achieve this?

Comment: the short answer is: you can use `map.myLocation`. The long answer is here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial#get-the-location-of-the-android-device-and-position-the-map

Answer (score 0):

try

```
map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(object :
            GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
            override fun onMyLocationButtonClick(): Boolean {

                return false
            }
        })
```